# Проверка массива на непрерывное возрастание цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру у нас есть массив:

```
nums = [7, 10, 9, 8, 6]
#Отсортировываем, большее к меньшему
nums.sort()
```

Так вот, как проверить что в этом массиве, есть 5 чисел которые возрастают непрерывно, к примеру в нашем случае это 6,7,8,9,10 - все 5 чисел возрастают непрерывно, возвращает истину, если нет ложь, отмечу что числа могут быть совершенно разные.

Comment: Поправьте текст, пожалуйста. `10` - не цифра, а число. Цифр только десять штук, все что из них составлено - числа. Ну и сами цифры тоже числа. Формулировка `5 цифр возрастают` отличается от `5 чисел возрастают` принципиально.

Comment: Решение в лоб: взять второй массив, уже отсортированный и сравнить с первым :D

Comment: Уже где-то был похожий вопрос

Comment: А что значит "возрастают непрерывно"? Есть какая-то дельта? Какая прогрессия? А если геометрическая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну это просто:

```
all(a - b == 1 for a,b in zip(nums[1:],nums))
```

Comment: спасибо, можно пожалуйста попросить вам еще что бы мы получали цифру до какого числа идёт возрастание в нашем случае до 10

Comment: Так в массиве из 5 чисел надо ответить "есть- ли 5 чисел которые возрастают непрерывно" и при этом вывести "до какого числа возрастают"? Вестимо до последнего элемента в массиве. Или нет такой возрастающей последовательности.

Comment: @passant проблема в том в массиве могут быть и не 5 чисел а гораздно больше, и все разные

Comment: @HedgeHog В том случае, если все они прирастают, то как сказал passant, нужно просто взять последний элемент отсортированного массива `nums[-1]`, либо мы все не поняли ваш вопрос, возможно

Comment: @CrazyElf, ваш ответ верен и все работает, но в массиве могут быть к примеру `[1,2,3,4,5,10,12,100,124,311]` Но прирост у нас идет только до 5, так вот как в вашем решении получить это  самое максимальное число до которого шло возрастание.

Comment: @HedgeHog А вариант только такой может быть? Ведь последовательностей таких может быть несколько, наверное, тогда какую из них брать - самую длинную? Или не самую длинную, но оканчивающуюся самым большим числом? Вариантов то много, нужно сначала чётко сформулировать задачу.

Comment: @HedgeHog Ну то есть будет, например, если `[1,2,3,4,5,10,12,100,101,102,103,311]`

Comment: @CrazyElf, требуется создать новый вопрос с более уточнёнными действиями?

Comment: @HedgeHog Думаю, да. И приведите там понятные примеры - какие могут быть данные и что вы ожидаете на выходе в каком из случаев. Но сначала воспользуйтесь поиском - на многие вопросы тут уже есть ответы на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

можно так:

```
nums = [7, 10, 9, 8, 6]
nums.sort()

print(nums == list(range(nums[0], nums[-1] + 1)))
```

думаю что так будет эффективней:

```
print((nums[-1] - nums[0]) == (len(set(nums)) - 1))
```

Comment: можно еще указать как вывести число до какого оно прирастает?

Comment: Кстати, под это решение можно подложить нехилую бомбу, если в конец списка `nums` злонамеренно положить очень-очень большое число )  То есть в боевых условиях прежде чем делать `list(range(` надо было бы ещё проверить равенство `nums[-1] - nums[0] + 1 == len(nums)`

Answer (score 0):

```
num = [ 7, 10, 9, 8, 6]
num = sorted(num)
b = []

for i in range(len(num)):
    b.append(num[0]+i)

for num, b in zip(num, b):
    print(num, b, sep=' - ')
```

Comment: А немного описать решение?

Answer (score 0):

Задача нужно уточнить перед решением. Массив сортировать не нужно, это можно сделать отдельно до вызова функции `five_numbers_in_a_row`. Если в массиве несколько растущих последовательностей, то выдадим только первую. Если первая последовательность длиннее пяти элементов, то выдадим только пять первых.

Итого: функция ищет первую подмассив вида `i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3, i + 4` и возвращает `i + 4`. Теперь можно решать.

Будем двигаться по массиву и считать последовательные растущие числа. `k` - число таких чисел до сих пор. Если новое число на единицу больше предыдущего, то увеличиваем `k`, иначе сбрасываем в единицу. Если `k` достигло пяти, возвращаем ответ.

```
def five_numbers_in_a_row(a):
    k = 0
    prev_v = None
    for v in a:
        if v - 1 == prev_v:
            k += 1
            if k == 5:
                return v
        else:
            k = 1
        prev_v = v
    return None
```

Тесты:

```
10   <- [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
5    <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 100, 101, 102, 103, 311]
104  <- [1, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 22, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 311]
None <- [1, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 22, 100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 311]
```